# Android Studio app crashes on launch when using ?colorVariant in xml drawable

Tags: java, android, xml, android-studio, android-layout

I have a shape in one of my xml drawables that uses the styles of my themes.xml file:

```
<shape android:shape="oval">
    <gradient
        android:gradientRadius="134dp"
        android:startColor="?colorPrimary"
        android:centerColor="#000000"
        android:endColor="#000111"
        android:type="radial" />
</shape>
```

As you can see startColor  uses the colorPrimary attribute. However, when I launch the app in the Android Studio emulator it crashes without build error. When I replace ?colorPrimary by a random hex color everything seems to be fine. I'm using API 24 and as far as I know you can use ?colorVariant for >API 21. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: You can still use something like @color/purple_500. The issue is not color reference

Comment: How could I refer to ?colorPrimary then? I'd like to have a different gradient when I'm using light and dark mode.

Comment: should it be `?attr/colorPrimary` ?

Comment: My app crashes if I use it

Comment: with `?attr/colorPrimary` ? and with `colorPrimary` defined in theme ?

Comment: Yes exactly. When I use a solid color and refer to colorPrimary I have no issue. This has something to do with the gradient

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use something like this `android:startColor="@color/purple_500"` see your colors.xml and call your colors from there

OR

If you want to use 2 colors for day and night go into your project directory `resources folder(res)` and create new folder name `drawable-night` and copy your `shape.xml` from `drawable` and paste it in `drawable-night` go to android studio now you have 2 `shape.xml` files one is night and the other one is for day add colors like you want to add like for
shape.xml add `android:startColor="@color/purple_500"` 
and for shape.xml(night) add `android:startColor="@color/purple_200"`

Comment: The issue is that I'd like to use different colors in light and dark mode

Comment: I updated my answer see if it's helpful for you